# VS Code - Extension Details Blank post "disable gpu" fix

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I apologize if this question has been answered somewhere else, but so far I am unable to locate it if it was.

**Background:**
As many folks have suffered the dreaded blank screen on VS Code, I deployed the recommended fix for --disable-gpu.  This fix worked just fine for me and I have been using it ever since.

**Issue:**
Since this fix has been deployed, I'm unable to view the details page when viewing an Extension.  The page/tab just shows up as blank.  This happens with any extension, regardless of if I've installed it or not.  This in and of itself is not a deal breaker for me, but I was hoping to use the Jupyter Notebook extension, but this seems to be impacting this as well.

If anyone has any guidance, please let me know.

[Screenshot showing lack of details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2yfY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this corrected by creating a .bat file that I use to open VS Code.  The code file was set up like the following:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\
Code.exe --disable-software-rasterizer --disable-gpu --no-sandbox
```